# Powershell Multi threading speed up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, powershell

I am going to use powershell to access some url ,and I want to speed it up, and I use the RunspacePool, please see the following code,

```
$throttleLimit = 100
$SessionState = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
$Pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $throttleLimit, $SessionState, $Host)
$Pool.Open()

$ScriptBlock = {
    param($id)

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    $resp = Invoke-RestMethod "http://google.com"  # some kind of url
    write-host "Done processing ID $id"
}

$threads = @()

$handles = for ($x = 1; $x -le 100; $x++) {
    $powershell = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($x)
    $powershell.RunspacePool = $Pool
    $powershell.BeginInvoke()
    $threads += $powershell
}

do {
  $i = 0
  $done = $true
  foreach ($handle in $handles) {
    if ($handle -ne $null) {
      if ($handle.IsCompleted) {
        $threads[$i].EndInvoke($handle)
        $threads[$i].Dispose()
        $handles[$i] = $null
      } else {
        $done = $false
      }
    }
    $i++
  }
  if (-not $done) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 }
} until ($done)
```

my question is: is there any configuration for the maximum connection size, because I set the maximum number of opened runspaces for the pool to 100, and I create 100 thread in that pool, but it seem they are not run in parallel, and they are take about 15 second to access google.com

Comment: Just for the record (not addressing your issue): 100 seems a bit high. Probably some folks already have desktops sitting there that would allow for really 100 threads to go in parallel; but most likely, your machine has a smaller capacity. I would start with with smaller values 4, 8 or so. And probably do some benchmarking in order to figure the number that gives you the best results on your hardware.

Comment: @GhostCat from the runing time, I can measure that it seem that it only run 5 threads at the same time, because 5 time faster than single thread, but where can I change the default value 5, thx

Comment: I would start with reading documentation about the components your code is using ...